# SVG Image not converted properly to Canvas using canvg

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, canvg

**Original SVG Chart**

[image: Original Chart]

**Rendered Canvas Chart**
[image: Rendered Canvas Chart]

**This is the code I am using to convert to canvas**

```
svg = $('svg').parent().html()
canvg('canvas', svg)
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
img_PNG = "<img src='#{canvas.toDataURL()}' />"

$('.chart').html(img_PNG)
```

Kindly help in sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the canvas element to canvg

```
svg = $('svg').parent().html()
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
canvg(canvas, svg)
img_PNG = "<img src='#{canvas.toDataURL()}' />"

$('.chart').html(img_PNG)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that only the bars are missing..i assume u have applied some animation to the bars..and svg is getting attached to the canvas before the animation..try to apply this code after animation and not before

img_PNG = " < img src='#{canvas.toDataURL()}' />"